# Android 4.3 Chrome flagging popup bug

Tags: bug, mobile-web, flag-dialog

When flagging a post with Chrome 30.0.1599.92 on Nexus 4 running Android 4.3, the popup goes below the textbox when choosing a flagging option which opens another popup, like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not only in android or Chrome, it's a bug in the mobile theme.

Comment: Darn it @ShaWizDowArd, I was just finding that dupe... (Stupid slow internet connection...)

Comment: @michaelb958 now the fame is all mine! <evil grin>